# I want to create custom numeric key pad

Tags: iphone

Hi all i want to create a cusom numeric key pad in iphone ,any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 3.2 you can easily do this - change the inputView property of your UITextField.

Comment: you'll need to add a view you have created like so: yourTextField.inputView = yourCustomViewController.view;

Comment: If you don't know how to create a view or view controller, I suggest practicing the basics with a simpler app. Creating your own numeric keypad is not as trivial as it sounds.